# parameter substitution in a binary string in python

Tags: python-3.x, binary-string

Python 3

I want to send a binary string over a socket. I am using

`socket.send(b"Hello from {0}",client_id)`

however I find the it is not properly substitution clientid.

what am I doing wrong? I do I accomplish this in a binary string

Answer (score 1):

`{0}` is a placeholder for the `str.format` method, which you should be using, but `bytes` objects do not have a `format` method; instead, you can format it as a string first and then convert it to `bytes` with the `encode` method:

```
socket.send("Hello from {0}".format(client_id).encode())
```